# Copy a table including DDL statements for an Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I Know of this below mentioned  command for copying table fully but i am not able to figure out how this command will work because i cant just find the mentioning of newly created table. (courtesy SO).

```
    SET LONG 5000
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'MY_OLD_TABLE_NAME' ) FROM DUAL;
```

And also i read in some oracle forum posts that this is  not a one shot solution to copy table ,its data and all the constraints , triggers , indexes and other such objects. 
IS this true ?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to export is use pl/sql developer or sql developer and use export data functionality. They export entire table with constraints, indexes, data. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant by "copy a table including DDL statements". If you are looking to create a new table using dbms_metadata.get_ddl, then the above command will actually need to be modified as (not tested) :-

Assuming that variable tbl_sql has been defined in plsql block having length of 32767, you can do :-

```
SELECT REPLACE(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','MY_OLD_TABLE_NAME'),32760,1),'MY_OLD_TABLE_NAME','NEW_TABLE_NAME') INTO tbl_sql FROM DUAL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE tbl_sql;
```

If you want to create a new table, then the following might be even better :-

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE_NAME AS SELECT * FROM MY_OLD_TABLE_NAME';
```

The dbms_metadata.get_ddl statement will not copy your data. However, the second statement (CTAS) will copy your data also.

Both the statements do not copy the constraints (CTAS does copy NOT NULL constraints) and indexes (as far as I know). To copy indexes, you will have to execute the dbms_metadata.get_ddl statement passing 'INDEX' as the first argument.

```
SELECT REPLACE(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX','MY_OLD_INDEX_NAME'),32760,1),'MY_OLD_INDEX_NAME','NEW_INDEX_NAME') INTO idx_sql FROM DUAL;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE idx_sql;
```

Comment: I tried running the first  command and it is not working .It says ORA-31603: object "my_old_table" of type TABLE not found in schema_name   
`
<pre>
 `Declare 
tbl_sql  varchar2(32767);
Begin 

SELECT REPLACE(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','my_old_table'),32760,1),'my_old_table','COPied_table) INTO tbl_sql FROM DUAL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE tbl_sql; 
TEST1';
end;`

Comment: replace "my_old_table" with the name of the table which you would like to copy. Also, check that you are executing this statement in the same schema in which the tables are present.

Comment: also be careful to recreate any default values in newly created table using CTAS, but sounds like this is what poster wants ("copying table fully"?)

Comment: I guess it is a typo but shouldn't `'COPied_table) INTO tbl_sql FROM`   actually be :-    `'COPied_table') INTO tbl_sql FROM`          in your example, the quotes start from Copied_Table and end at Test1

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple

```
create table xyz_new as select * from xyz where 1=0;
```

**Create table with indexes ( More useful )**

```
create table xyz_new like xyz
```

Comment: This command only copies structure and data, it doesn't copy indexes and constraints